# How can I tell if service and systemctl are the same command?

Tags: systemd, services

I'm trying to run Nginx using Systemd as a process manager.

When I run `sudo service nginx start` and then type `ps -aux | grep nginx` it appears to be the same process running as when I started it using `sudo systemctl start nginx`.

Is this the case, that `service` could be mapped to `systemctl`? How can I tell?

When I look at `/etc/init.d/nginx` the script is very different from the config at `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`.

However, if I start nginx using the `systemctl` command and then stop it using the `service` command that works fine. Same in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo strace -f -e trace=process service nginx status 2>&1 | grep systemctl
```

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes, "There's more than one way to cat a file".  In this case, it's not absolutely clear what you mean by 'the same process running', so I'll explain both possible issues.

If what you mean is that you have the same process ID running if you first do a 'systemctl ngix start', and then do a 'service ngix start'.  This would be because if a daemon is already running, a 'start' process will not shut it down and start a new one.  In such a situation, the result should be a no-op.   Do a *stop* before you do a subsequent *start*, or use a *restart* command instead.

If you did do a stop (or a reboot) between the two *start* commands, and you're seeing ngix running in both cases -- with the same parameters to the command, even though the process IDs are different, then the 'problem' is that in both cases, the ultimate goal is to get ngix running. The locations of content and configuration files don't change. The options you want to use  don't change just because different programs start them.  It's pretty much just a case of 'all roads lead to Rome'.

Finally, if you suspect that *systemctl* and *service* are links to the same file, then try.

```
cmp `which systemctl` `which service`
```

That will tell you if *systemctl* and *service* both contain exactly the same code (and/or are links to the same file).

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with `which systemctl` and `which service`, and then look at the output of `ls -l` for both to see if they are the same file (via symlink) or look similar (size, etc).

At least here (Fedora 23) `/usr/bin/systemctl` is a binary, `/usr/sbin/service` is a shell script that uses systemd commands to emulate the SysVinit command.

Comment: What do you mean by "a shell script that uses systemd commands to emulate the SysVinit command"? I believe what's happening is that `service nginx start` is running this shell script that _invokes_ the systemctl command...plus a lot of other stuff. `systemctl start nginx` seems to just start the SystemD process.

Probably a separate question, but is one way of running nginx better than the other?

Comment: @YPCrumble, just that here `service` uses the very same `systemd` machinery to offer the legacy functionality.